# How to set pie chart label format as a cellformat programmatically in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm generating a pie chart from a set of data.

- The chart labels have the value and the percentage.
- I want to format the value as the one in the cell using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)

I don't know where to start.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link the number format of the labels to the number format of the cell. Via the UI you'd do this by formatting the labels and on the Number tab select "Link to source".

If you run the macro recorder during that, you will get the respective VBA, i.e. link

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormatLinked = -1
```

and unlink

```
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormatLinked = 0
```

Comment: When I do the link, it links the pourcentage not the value

Comment: If you ***link*** to the source, then the percentage will show as a percentage and the value will show as formatted in the source cell. If you ***unlink*** from the source, both percentage and value will show the format of the Number tab in the Format Labels dialog.